# C# Convert string to const string

Tags: c#, tcp

I am working on a tcp server and client and I need to convert user input(Console.ReadLine();) to an existing const string. Heres the code:

```
    const int PORT_NO = 8080;
    const string SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
    public static void MainClient()
    {

        SERVER_IP = Console.ReadLine(); //I need help here :(

        //The boring stuff
    }
```

btw: The tcp code requires const string so I cant just remove it and use regular string value

Comment: why not drop `const` then? `static string SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";`. If you change the declaration, `SERVER_IP = Console.ReadLine();` will be perfectly legal

Comment: If you _change_ it, it is not *const*ant anymore, is it?

Comment: @Fildor: It is until it's changed again ;)

Comment: The method that I use later in the tcp server code requires const string. I forgot to say that

Comment: @TerThesz - How does the tcp server know the variable hasn't been declared as a `const`? The moment you call `SERVER_IP` as a parameter you'll loose the fact that it's const.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! I didnt read the error. It can be a regulas string value but the function cant be static. Heres the final code

```
const int PORT_NO = 8080;
string SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
public void MainClient()
{

    SERVER_IP = Console.ReadLine(); //I need help here :(

    //The boring stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A constant decalred with `const` [cannot be modified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/const).

> You use the const keyword to declare a constant field or a constant local. Constant fields and locals aren't variables and may not be modified.

Remove the `const` keyword to make your field a variable and add `static` instead, otherwise you cannot access the field in your static `MainClient` method.

Comment: I have just edited the post. I need the string to be const for the tcp client to work

Comment: What happens if it is not `const`? Why does the TCP client not work then?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a value to a field which is const at compile time. Instead, you could make the field readonly and assign the value you read from console in the class constructor. That would be my approach, if I understood your problem correctly. Something like:

```
const int PORT_NO = 8080;
readonly string SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
public static void MainClient()
{

    SERVER_IP = Console.ReadLine(); //I need help here :(

    //The boring stuff
}
```

Hope this helps.